# Apache Velocity Template Language - Ignore invalid references

Tags: java, apache, velocity, template-engine

Suppose I want to parse a map like this in VTL.

```
map - { "person" = "xyz", age="99" }
```

Using VTL, I would call `$map.person` and `$map.age` to insert the appropriate values in the template.

Now suppose the map does not hold any valid value for the key "person"

```
map - { age="99" }
```

If I call `$map.person` , VTL simply will return `$map.person`. *I want to ignore such a reference from being parsed at all. How can I achieve this?*

Comment: Does VTL have a function to detect empty values? I'm using the EL language from JEE in my templates and there is a ${empty abc.def} function which tells me if something is present. I would expect that VTL has something similar.

Comment: Yes. I could check for #if (map.person) and rewrite the template accodringly. However I'm parsing a template where each line has several such parameters to be checked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

silent notation.  yep, it's in the manual.

$!map.person